# How does Enum.map works with Task.await?

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, async-await, elixir

How does Elixir `Enum.map([Task.t], &Task.await)` work?

```
async_1 = Task.async(fn ->
  IO.inspect("done async 1") 
  1
end)

async_2 = Task.async(fn ->
  IO.inspect("done async 2")
  2
end)

results = Enum.map([async_1, async_2], fn(task) ->
  IO.inspect("starting new task")
  IO.inspect(task)
  Task.await(task) 
end)

IO.inspect(results)
```

From the code above, I got the IO log:

```
"starting new task"
"done async 1"
"done async 2"
%Task{pid: #PID<0.51.0>, ref: #Reference<0.0.0.78>}
"starting new task"
%Task{pid: #PID<0.52.0>, ref: #Reference<0.0.0.79>}
[1, 2]
```

1. I would expect the second `"starting new task"` showed up before `"done async 2"` did. How did it execute all the async tasks eagerly?
2. From the [doc](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.html#await/2), it says `await` will "Awaits a task reply and returns it". I assumed it means it's going to pause the caller process till a finish message has been sent back from the `Task` process. If that is the case, It should pause on each invoke of `Task.await(Task.t)` in each `map` iteration and never really perform those tasks concurrently. The log has proven that my assumption is wrong. But where is it wrong?

Here is my repl http://elixirplayground.com?gist=f1fa90eadc00441a360d8bc883d64529

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Task.async` doesn't wait until `Task.await` to run the function passed to it; it starts running it instantly. The work given to the tasks here is very small and so both of them are already finished executing it by the time `Enum.map` gets the chance to await the second task.

Answer (score 0):

Thank @Dogbert for the enlightenment. I had misunderstood `Task.async` in Elixir.

It confused me because in ES7 and C#, `async` is just a keyword indicates that the function is going to return a `Promise` or an `Asyncable`. `async` is only in charged to define "async_function". `await` does two things - execute and wait for results. i.e.

```
function async(action: fn): Promise
function await(async_action: Promise): ?Any { execute_and_wait(async_function) }
```

In Elixir, `Task.async` will execute the function in a new process, which is similar to `start_link`. And `await` only waits for the executing process to return results.

Not saying the design is unreasonable. But I would much prefer they have called it something else than `async` because it's breaking the conventions from other common languages thus harder to learn.